# CSS show absolute value

Tags: css

Is there any tricks to get CSS to show absolute values?

```
<div value="-30">-30</div>
```

I want to see 30.

I can use pseudo elements to visually replace it but for arbitrary numbers it would lead to an unreasonably long CSS file.

Comment: Some context might be useful. Why CSS instead of placing the absolute value into the content itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, but I suppose it is wrong approach, it is better to output absolute values in html from the very beginning

```css
div[value^="-"]:first-letter {
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div value="1">1</div>
<div value="-2">-2</div>
<div value="3">3</div>
```